# PHP Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I do not understand why the content is not visible no browser.

index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Teste</title>
  </head>
  <body>

     @yield('content')

  </body>
</html>
```

conteudo.blade.php

```
@extends('index')

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('index', function() {
   return view('layouts/index');

});

Route::get('blade', function() {
   return view('layouts/conteudo');

});
```

Comment: Wait, so you've got a layouts folder, that has both your index.blade.php file in AND your conteudo.blade.php file in it? Shouldn't you still have to have `@extends('layouts.index')` in @conteudo.blade.php?

Comment: yes, I have two files in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

please change your `conteudo.blade.php` code

```
@extends('index')

@section('content')
   <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

To

```
@extends('layouts.index')

@section('content')
   <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

Hope this helps you.